# how to show underscores symbol in markdown?

Tags: markdown, r-markdown

in markdown, `my_stock_index` is my*stock*index. But I want it to show `my_stock_index`. How can do that?

Comment: Which implementation of Markdown are you using?

Comment: @Chris, Markdown Pad

Comment: @Chris do you mean that this isn't standard behavior?

Comment: @lulalala, many Markdown questions on SO target some implementation other than [the original](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and some common implementations handle this differently, e.g. [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/#emphasis-and-strong-emphasis) and [GitLab Flavored Markdown](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#multiple-underscores-in-words).

Answer (score 259, accepted):

You just escape it with a backslash:
`my\_stock\_ticker` is what you type to get `my_stock_ticker`

The syntax [seems to work for almost all markdown parsers](https://babelmark.github.io/?text=my%5C_name%5C_%0A%0Amy_name_). However, php markdown parsers use the numeric character reference `&#95;` instead of the actual character in it's output.

Comment: This does not seem to work on github markdown ... It converts the letters to subscript instead.

Comment: @Finomnis for github flavoured markdown, escaping the underscore is not necessary. E.g. `my_stock_ticker` will already appear as 'my_stock_ticker' (i.e. it will be rendered with the underscores). Note most linters will probably think it's a syntax error though.

Comment: you can also use `gsub("_", "\\_", string)`

Answer (score 40):

There is also the option to use backticks. This is actually used to refer to mark the text as inline code, but where else would you use underscores right? Besides it is much easier than managing the backslash stuff :)

```
`my_stock_index`
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good solution when you don't have control over the individual characters and can't necessarily escape them

Comment: You are right, "where else would I use underscores"? :)

Comment: This is the best answer. I prefer it to mine.

Answer (score 30):

The single backslash escape works fine in Jupyter unless you are in an italicized block, in which case, you want to close the italicized block, write the escaped underscore, then start the italicized block again.

```
_the cookie_\__cutter in italics_
```

Comment: Or you can use  `*the cookie\_cutter in italics*` and avoid the extra closing.

Comment: Wow, you are a lifesaver! Thank you so much!