# How to print an asterisk ('*') in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to write in my R Markdown "3 times 6:10 and (3 times 6):10" all in complete letters (I am using times instead of *. My purpose is to put * instead of word times without any problem). However, it keeps giving me italic syntax for the part "6:10 and (3". How can I write my *s in R Markdown straight into the document without evoking * syntax which is make letters italic in the middle?

Comment: very. \_very\_ related. https://stackoverflow.com/q/35827838/7941188

Answer (score 37):

### Escape '*' by using '\*' instead

Alternatively, you could use `$\times$` to get the '×' symbol

Answer (score 17):

On the web use `&ast;`

That's one of it's HTML codes.
(Only mention it because google brought me here when I didn't search about the R language and figure others will end up here as well.)

Comment: For clarity, this also works in Rmarkdown

Comment: Wild.  Revisiting this and there's 4 distinct ways to do it.  (1) spaces around it ` * `  (2) escape with `\*`  (3) use/set LaTeX times symbol instead with `$\times$`  (4) html code `&ast;`

Answer (score 11):

Markdown is quite sensitive to whitespace. If you don't put spaces around the * (line 3 below) you get the problem you're describing (markdown assumes the *s are italic-delimiters).

Some possible solutions

- line 5: add spaces, no problem (except you might not want that spacing)
- line 7 (@CaptainHat): set times as a LaTeX times symbol
- line 9: set in code format
- line 11 (@CaptainHat): protect *s with backslashes

Also tried @CaptainHat's suggestions as well as type-setting in code format ...)
[image]

Other possibilities are to use the letter "x" for multiplication, or (if available on your keyboard/via compose-key) to use the × symbol ([Unicode 00D7](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00D7): instructions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign#Typing_the_character)).

Answer (score 0):

## Use Asterisk `'*'` in Markdown:

### First Solution:

In markdown, print the asterisk symbol `'*'` with the help of the backslash symbol `'\'`.

> Example: `\*`

### Second Solution:

In markdown, print the asterisk symbol `'*'` with the help of the backtick symbol **( ` )**

[image: Print asterisk using quote with the backtick symbol]